# Curious: is it possible to have dynamic Ajax data variable names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, variables

**Some background:**

On a recent project, I tried to write a streamlined jQuery plugin that would handle some Ajax calls made when various inputs were updated. I wrote the JavaScript function as a plugin so that I could just call it on various inputs, like so:

```
$("#email").updateChanges();
```

Then, from within the plugin, I collected the input's id, value, etc.

**The problem:**

Something that I really wanted to do, but couldn't find a solution for, was to dynamically generate the name of the data variable being passed through ajax.

**To be more clear, given this function:**

```
jQuery.fn.updateChanges = function(){

   this.bind('blur',function(){

      var inputName = $(this).attr("name");
      var inputValue = $(this).val();

      $.post('/ajax/updateValue.php',
        { email: inputValue }, function(ret){
           if (ret=='success') alert("all good!");
        }

   }

}
```

...how do I present the data for the Ajax call as `{ password: inputValue }` instead of `{ email: inputValue }` when the inputName variable is "password" instead of "email"? This is a very specific example, but basically I'm just looking for a way to read the name of the data variable from a separate dynamic variable.

I tried `window[inputName]` with no luck, and I'm pretty much convinced this is impossible. However, if someone has an idea, I'd be very impressed.

Incidentally, we ended up going with `{ type: inputName, value: inputValue }` instead, but it required a little bit more legwork on the PHP side (don't ask me, I'm just the front-end guy :).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you planning to communicate the desired variable name to the function? Will it be a parameter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you're after:

```
jQuery.fn.updateChanges = function(){

   this.bind('blur',function(){    

      var data = {};
      data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();

      $.post('/ajax/updateValue.php',
        data,
        function(ret){
           if (ret=='success') alert("all good!");
        }    
   }    
}
```

Your main issue was attempting to use a dynamic value using the object literal notation, something you cannot do without reverting to really bad practices (like using eval() where eval() doesn't belong ;).

```
var myObj = { 'n1': 'v1' };
```

is equivalent to:

```
var myObj = {}; // {} = new Object();
myObj['n1'] = 'v1';
```

is equivalent to:

```
var myObj = {},
    myKey = 'n1',
    myVal = 'v1';

myObj[myKey] = myVal;
```

Comment: Wow, that's great. Exactly what I was looking for. So much more to learn!

Answer (score -1):

try with this:

```
jQuery.fn.updateChanges = function(){

   this.bind('blur',function(){

      var inputName = $(this).attr("id");
      var inputValue = $(this).val();
      var data = eval("{"+ inputName  +":"+ inputValue  +" }");

      alert("send: "+ inputName+"\n"+data[inputName]);

      $.post('/ajax/updateValue.php',
        data, function(ret){
           if (ret=='success') alert("all good!");
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: eval is slow, dirty and dangerous. Avoid it.

Comment: ok, we'll forward it to John Resig for change in the line of 3725 "jQuery-1.3.2.js" -> 'window [ "eval"]'. Because of you I guess nobody uses jQuery. 
Who is right?.
window [ "eval"] return the native "eval()"